# Virtnetwork Cannot Start Virtualizor KVM

Tags: linux

I have a problem with my virtnetwork. I have set the correct network interface on master setting Virtualizor but it said

> /etc/sysconfig/: error fetching interface information: Device not
>   found Error: No ip address found.

when I try to run

```
service virtnetwork start
```

Does anyone can help me? Here is my network interface "ifcfg-ens9"

```
NAME="ens9"
DEVICE="ens9"
ONBOOT=yes
NETBOOT=yes
UUID="805c90c6-a8d2-49f1-8707-44696466a9fa"
IPV6INIT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
TYPE=Ethernet
DNS1=127.0.0.1
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPADDR=xxx.xxx.187.234
PREFIX=29
GATEWAY=xxx.xxx.187.233
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
```

Looking forward for the solution. I don't know whats wrong the setting above.

Comment: Which distro/kernel?

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this issue because netmask is not defined in the file and you are not using standard name eth0 for nic.

Set netmask instead of prefix and also goto

admin panel of Virtualizor -> configuration -> slave settings(choose server from dropdown) -> ens9 -> save.

Then restart virtnetwork, it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Only change the slave setting to the name of the network interface and after that try to start virtnetwork , if it have problem please make sure that the network interface had GW in the file and after that it will work fine....