# Virtnetwork and Netplan

Tags: virtualization, ubuntu-18.04

I setup the bridge with netplan on ubuntu 18.04, everythin look ok:

```
br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet myip  netmask 255.255.255.192  broadcast someip
        inet6 myip  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether hidden txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 27382  bytes 5374960 (5.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8381  bytes 2177553 (2.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet myip  netmask 255.255.255.192  broadcast someip
        ether 28:92:4a:36:8f:0e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 31969  bytes 8078978 (8.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8955  bytes 2267155 (2.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xfbee0000-fbf00000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 15298  bytes 4480739 (4.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 15298  bytes 4480739 (4.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

As you can see the br0 bridge network is fine.

I can start the virtnetwork.service but I have no Bridges networks on it:

```
virtnetwork[11291]: Error: No ip address found.
```

My slave settings looks fine with the br0 name on it I also tried with enp2s0.

Any help is appreciate.

Comment: Is this about Virtualizor?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes

Comment: [This question](https://serverfault.com/q/873343/126632) appears to be virtually identical except for being on CentOS. But the answer might help you anyway.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I already look at this question but on ubuntu 18.04 we are using netplan and netmask is on my configuration file also the slave settings are right.

Comment: Really? What is your netplan configuration?